# Blender crashes when I change number of vertices in the scene

Tags: mesh, vertices, error, versions

When I add a cylinder or change the number of vertices in the scene, blender crashes/closes instantly

Video describing my issue:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JijmNMtQ4lY)

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Seems like a memory issue. Although multiple things could be causing this. Mind adding your system specifications ?

Comment: I have 16G ram
I look at the Task Manager when the blender crash, the only about 40-50% ram is used
and also every time I change the number of vertices, the blender crash!

Comment: B85-M motherboard, intel i5 4460 3.20 GHz cpu, GTX960 display card

Comment: Seems odd are you using experimental builds by any chance ?

Comment: I think when the .blend file is about 200,000KB, this crash comes up!
Before this, I had few similar experience.
Is there any relation between the file size and the crash? thank you!